# Universal Quantification in Haskell Instance Contexts?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

**Original Question**

I would like to make the following work:

```
class Functor2 c where
   fmap2 :: (a->b) -> c x a -> c x b

instance Functor (c x) => Functor2 c where
  fmap2 = fmap
```

However I get the error:

```
Could not deduce (Functor (c x1)) arising from a use of `fmap'
from the context (Functor (c x))
```

How can I do it?

---

**My use case**

I want to use the `Arrow` methods (and sugar, etc) for my `Applicative` instances. More specifically I want:

```
newtype Wrap f g a b = W   { unwrap  :: ( f (g a b) ) } 

instance (Category g, "Forall x." Applicative (g x), Applicative f) => Arrow (Wrap f g)
```

This instance would automatically follow from these (already working) instances:

```
instance (Category g, Applicative f) => Category (Wrap f g) where
  id = W $ pure id
  (W x) . (W y) = W $ liftA2 (.) x y

instance (Applicative (g x), Applicative f) => Functor (Wrap f g x) where
  fmap f = W . fmap (fmap f) . unwrap

instance (Applicative (g x), Applicative f) => Applicative (Wrap f g x) where
  pure = W . pure . pure
  (W ab) <*> (W a)  = W $ pure (<*>) <*> ab <*> a
```

if I could get this one to work:

```
instance (Category c, "Forall x." Applicative (c x)) => Arrow c where
  arr f = (pure f) <*> id
  first a = pure (,) <*> (arr fst >>> a) <*> (arr snd)
```

The types of `arr` and `first` check out in the compiler. The problem is the required `"Forall x."`, which I do not know how to state in Haskell.

An easy example for such a `g` is `->`: `Category (->)` and `Applicative ((->) x)` for all `x`.

Comment: Can't. Sorry about that.

Comment: Not even with something like https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/constraint-kind.html ?

Comment: Can you show us an intended use case in which you would really need such a `fmap2` while `fmap` would not type check?

Comment: How about adding the constraint to the class definition instead? i.e. Making Functor a superclass

Comment: @is7s `class Functor (c x) => Functor2 c` gives `Not in scope: type variable \`x'`

Comment: When is `fmap2` not equal to `fmap`?

Comment: @DavidYoung I am not sure, what are are trying to figure out and how it would relate to my use case. Could you be more specific?

Comment: That suspiciously looks like a [bifunctor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/categories-1.0.6/docs/Control-Categorical-Bifunctor.html) thing. In fact, I think, your `Functor2` would be an Endo-`QFunctor` in `(->)`.

Comment: @phg Trying to find a way to use this to solve by problem... Can provide more detail?

Answer (score 1):

This does not really achieve your goal, but maybe it could be a step forward.
Your `forall x. Functor (c x)` is written `AllFunctor2 c` in this approach.
The main drawback is that you have to provide an instance to every functor you want to put in that class.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

data Ftor f where
   Ftor :: Functor f => Ftor f

class AllFunctor2 c where
   allFtor2 :: Ftor (c a)

instance AllFunctor2 (->) where
   allFtor2 = Ftor

fmap2 :: AllFunctor2 c => (a->b) -> c x a -> c x b
fmap2 f (x :: c x a) = case allFtor2 :: Ftor (c x) of Ftor -> fmap f x
```

Probably the above is not so different from providing instances to `Functor2` directly:

```
class Functor2 c where
   fmap2 :: (a->b) -> c x a -> c x b

instance Functor2 (->) where
   fmap2 = fmap
```